# Get the Type of an object's children in silktest

Tags: testing, automation, silktest

Assume i have an object and it has lots of children.May i know how i can find their types?

I first used **getChildren()** to get the children and then used **typeof()** for each child.

Typeof always returns
Window.

I would like to find if they are DomTextField or DomLink etc and not Window.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `yourParent.FindAll(/DomTextField)`, this will give you all direct children, if you want to include all descendants, use `yourParent.FindAll(//DomTextField)`.